# HTML 5 media stream for video recording issue on record function

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote html 5 code for video recording and uploading. When click on start button it will produce a javascript error. 
"TypeError: webcamstream.record is not a function streamRecorder = webcamstream.record();"
"TypeError: streamRecorder is undefined streamRecorder.getRecordedData(postVideoToServer);"

It is only for mozilla browser.Please help me...Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var streamRecorder;
var webcamstream;

function enter()
{

if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
   navigator.myGetMedia=navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
   navigator.myGetMedia({video: true}, connect, error); 
} 
else { 
   alert("N");
}

function connect(stream) 


{



    var video = document.getElementById("my_video");
    video.src = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
    webcamstream = stream;
    video.play();



  }

  function error(e) { console.log(e); }



}

 function startRecording() 
    {
      alert('STARTING');
      streamRecorder = webcamstream.record();
      setTimeout(stopRecording, 10000);
    }
 function stopRecording() 
    {
        alert('STOP');
        streamRecorder.getRecordedData(postVideoToServer);
    }
  function postVideoToServer(videoblob) {

     alert ('start video uploaded');
        var data = {};
        data.video = videoblob;
        data.metadata = 'test metadata';
        data.action = "upload_video";
        jQuery.post("http://www.kongraju.in/uploadvideo.php", data, onUploadSuccess);
    }

    function onUploadSuccess() {
        alert ('video uploaded');
    }

  </script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas width="640" height="480" id="c"></canvas>
<input type="button" value="START CAMERA" onClick="enter()"/>
<input type="button" value="START RECORD" onClick="startRecording()"/>
<input type="button" value="STOP RECORD" onClick="stopRecording()"/>
<video id="my_video" width="640" height="480"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think `MediaStreamRecorder` of `MediaStream.record()` is implemented in any browser yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification draft of the getMediaStream API there is no method called record() [W3C mediacapture draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#methods)

You can try to achieve recording by drawing each frame on a canvas and saving it to a temporary Image File using the new File System API. Maybe I can provide you an example later on. It has already been done using Webkit-Engine. See [here](https://gist.github.com/piatra/2549734)

Comment: The `MediaStrea.record` method the OP is trying to use is specified as an extension of `MediaStream` [in the MediaStreamReorder API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc-20111004.html#widl-MediaStream-record-MediaStreamRecorder), but no browser has implemented this API yet.

Comment: But i how to send audio with image to the server in your case.